# Reducing a mixed Boolean expression containing XOR of conjunctions

Tags: satisfiability

I know that XOR-SAT can be solved in polynomial time using arithmetic in $F_2$ and Gaussian elimination.

I have a set of formula that is of the form

$$
G_i := \oplus_{j=0}^{i} \left ( a_j \land b_{i-j} \right )
$$

where $a_k, b_k$ are the variables and $\oplus$ denotes XOR and $\land$ denotes logical AND.

Is there any standard reduction I could apply to these formulae to solve them using XOR-SAT?

I need to solve the conjunction of $\land_{i} G_i$.

Edit: The $G_i$ are known.

Comment: Are you familiar with Schaefer's theorem?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: Did you mean this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schaefer%27s_dichotomy_theorem

Comment: Yes. You should be able to tell whether your type of CSP is feasible or not.

Comment: So, if I understand your hint correctly, you are saying replace $a_j \land b_{i-j}$ with new variables $x_m$. Now $G_i$ is a set of affine relations and solving it is in $P$. We then solve the set of relations $x_m$ that are all conjunctions. Is that correct?

Comment: My guess is that your problem is NP-complete, and you should be able to show it using Schaefer's theorem.

Comment: Are there any constraints you are hiding from us? Are the variables $a_k,b_k$ completely arbitrary?

Comment: The $G_i$ are known. I have edited the question to clarify this.

Comment: Naturally you know your instance. The question is whether the instance has any other constraints. Is the $i$'th constraint really an XOR of exactly $i$ ANDs? Do the same variables $a_k,b_k$ appear in all constraints? Presumably not, but it's hard to tell from your description. Perhaps you could give some examples of instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit hard to understand, so let me interpret it in the following way. You are interested in Boolean CSPs (that is, constraint satisfaction problems over Boolean variables) in which the constraints are of the form
$$
\bigoplus_{i=1}^n (a_i \land b_i) = 1,
$$
where $a_1,\ldots,a_n,b_1,\ldots,b_n$ are arbitrary *variables* (rather than literals), which can possibly repeat. The value of $n$ can be any natural number.

According to [Schaefer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schaefer%27s_dichotomy_theorem), if $S$ is a collection of Boolean predicates that $\mathit{CSP}(S)$ can be solved in polynomial time if one of the following is a polymorphism of all predicates in $S$:

- The constant 0 function.
- The constant 1 function.
- The binary AND function.
- The binary OR function.
- The ternary XOR function.
- The ternary majority function.

(Here binary means that the function has two inputs, and ternary means that it has three inputs.)

If none of these are polymorphisms of $S$, then $\mathit{CSP}(S)$ is NP-complete.

In your case, $S$ is an infinite collection of predicates $\{ P_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$. Fortunately, using the theorem it is easy to check that $\mathit{CSP}(\{P_2\})$ is already NP-complete, and so your problem is also NP-complete.